# How do I add HTML code to a widget with wp-cli?

Tags: wp-cli

I want to add a YouTube video to a widget via wp-cli. The YouTube video is basically an iframe. When I execute the following command:

```
wp-cli widget update text-1 --text='<iframe src="http://example.com"></iframe>'
```

the text of the widget is empty. It seems either wp-cli or wordpress is stripping away the iframe tags. Via the wordpress backend it is possible to add arbitrary html to a text widget. But via wp-cli it does not work.

Is there some command line option or workaround? Going directly via the DB with MySQL would be the last option.

Thx in advance!

Comment: maybe a dumb question but is the name of the widget "text-1"?  If it is, can you try updating the title like in this command? wp widget update test-1 --title="Our Calendar" maybe the field you want to update is not called "text"?